# widget based web framework for scala

Tags: scala

I am trying to move from java to scala . I am basically a web developer where i use zkoss, vaadin as my framework. Do scala has widget based framework.Fully ajax based? I haven't tried lift and play need some advice is that fully ajax based?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Vaadin framework can be used with Scala. There is even a project called [Scaladin](https://github.com/henrikerola/scaladin/wiki) to help you with that. Since you already know it, I suggest you try learning scala with that framework. After you have a good understand of scala you should have a better base for what framework to choose in case you want to leave Vaadin.

Here are some resources:

- [Scala and Vaadin HOWTO](https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Scala+and+Vaadin+HOWTO)
- [Scaladin wiki](https://github.com/henrikerola/scaladin/wiki)
- [Develop Vaadin apps with Scala](http://morevaadin.com/content/develop-vaadin-apps-scala)

Answer (score 1):

Try [Scala+GWT](http://scalagwt.github.com/) with one of web frameworks (Lift, Play and etc.)